# How to replace a character from a column having space in column name in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, boto3

I want to change the datatype of a column and replace something

```
reader = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(body), delimiter=',',encoding='utf8',usecols=cols)
```

and then i want to perform operation through all these

```
reader['column A']=reader['column A'].astype(str).replace('\.0', '', regex=True)
```

But i am not able to perform it is giving me KeyError: 'column A'. can someone please help me to identify the problem and resolve it

when I use columns having no space then it is running fine.like`reader['columnB']=reader['columnB'].astype(str)`

Comment: What headers does the CSV contain? Is "column A" actually a header in the CSV?

Comment: Yes it is there. Initially even I thought the same and crosschecked it twice

Comment: Can you add an example of the CSV to the question?